# How to get values that doesn't pass from FilterIterator

Tags: php, performance, optimization, filter-iterator

I'm using FilterIterator to filter out the values and implemented the **accept()** method successfully. However I was wondering how would it be possible to get the values that returned false from my accept method in single iteration. Let's take the code below as an example (taken from **php.net**);

```
class UserFilter extends FilterIterator 
{
    private $userFilter;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator , $filter )
    {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->userFilter = $filter;
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        $user = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        if( strcasecmp($user['name'],$this->userFilter) == 0) {
            return false;
        }        
        return true;
    }
}
```

On the code above, it directly filters out the values and returns the values that pass from the filteriterator. Implemented as;

```
$array = array(
array('name' => 'Jonathan','id' => '5'),
array('name' => 'Abdul' ,'id' => '22')
);

$object = new ArrayObject($array);
$iterator = new UserFilter($object->getIterator(),'abdul');
```

It will contain only the array with name **Jonathan**. However I was wondering would it be possible to store the object with name **Abdul** in another variable using the same filter with a slight addition instead of **reimplementing the entire filter to do the opposite**?. One way I was thinking would exactly copy paste the FilterIterator and basically change values of **true** and **false**. However are there any neat ways of doing it, since it will require another traversal on the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must rewrite the `accept()` mechanic. Instead of returning true or false, you may want to break down the array to

```
$result = array(
    'passed' => array(...),
    'not_passed' => array(...)
);
```

Your code may look like this

```
if (strcasecmp($user['name'], $this->userFilter) == 0) {
    $result['not_passed'][] = $user;
} else {
    $result['passed'][] = $user;
}

return $result;
```